# bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i make control panel and there is a problem with jquery (data-toggle) not working and this message appear in console" bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery     at bootstrap.min.js:6 "
this is footer file

```
   <div calss="footer">

 </div>
 <script src="<?php echo $js; ?>jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo $js; ?>jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=" <?php echo $js; ?>bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo $js; ?>jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo $js; ?>backend.js"></script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

and i include footer

```
include $tpl.'footer.php';
```

and thats working in main site with the same folders and pathes and names
i dont know whats wrong

Comment: truly frustrating, there are several questions on this topic and it the same, change the order. I have the exact order listed in the official docs and same thing, not loading...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change the order of files it should be like below..

```
<script src="<?php echo $js; ?>jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $js; ?>bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $js; ?>jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $js; ?>jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></></script>
<script src="<?php echo $js; ?>backend.js"></script>
```

Comment: the same problem :/